# Django: how to get entry position based on the it's rating

Tags: python, django, rating

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

There are two TOPs:

- by rating in world
- by rating in country

I need to provide **position** in every rating.
F.e.

Blogs in db:

- Blog(name='Python', rating=100, country='Russia')
- Blog(name='Django', rating=10, country='Russia')
- Blog(name='Programming', rating=5, country='France')
- Blog(name='Stackoverflow', rating=9, country='Latvia')

Top by rating in world:

1. Blog(name='Python', rating=100, country='Russia')
2. Blog(name='Django', rating=10, country='Russia')
3. Blog(name='Stackoverflow', rating=9, country='Latvia')
4. Blog(name='Programming', rating=5, country='France')

Top rating by country Russia:

1. Blog(name='Python', rating=100, country='Russia')
2. Blog(name='Django', rating=10, country='Russia')

How can i get blog's position based on the rating?

**UPDATE:**

I should be able to do somethink like this:

```
Blog.objects.get(pk=1).world_position # output = 23
Blog.objects.get(pk=1).country_position # output = 14
```

Because of that simple iterating with order_by('rating') doesn't fit.

Comment: for rating in world sort by rating, for rating in country filter by country and sort by rating.

Comment: @IonutHulub look at **UPDATE**

Answer (score 1):

Should be as simple as this

```
for i, blog in enumerate(Blog.objects.all().order_by('-rating')):
    i, blog 
Blog.objects.filter(country='Russia').order_by('-rating')
```

You could look at Raw Sql to get row number if you have very large dataset

UPDATE : Although this is not efficient for large dataset and you should consider using RAW SQL to get rownumber, or you could find a way to store the ranking based on rating for blog objects.

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    @property
    def world_position(self):
        ids = list(Blog.objects.all().order_by('-rating').values_list('id', flat=True))
        return ids.index(self.id)
```

Comment: I need to get **POSITION** (1, 2, 3, 4, .., 512), not just order_by rating.

Comment: Django Querysets are lazy. I think the best way to get position is plain iteration.

Comment: Iteration either doesn't fit. Because i should be able to do sthm like this:

Blog.objects.get(pk=23).world_position

Comment: use extra on queryset to add world_position to your retrieved objects